# Check if new start time and end time is not in conflict with existing start time and end time for the same date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Schedule table with these columns:

```
LeaveDate DateTime
Start_Time varchar
End_Time varchar
```

Before I add a value I need a query that will check first if my Start_Time, End_Time and LeaveDate input does not conflict with existing records.

Here's my existing record:

```
Rec LeaveDate  Start_Time   End_Time
1   01/01/2017 9:00:00      13:30:00
```

Valid Input - Note that new Start_Time can be equal to existing End_Time of the same date:

```
LeaveDate  Start_Time   End_Time
01/01/2017 13:30:00     18:00:00
```

Or

```
LeaveDate  Start_Time   End_Time
01/01/2017 13:43:00     18:00:00
```

Invalid Input:

```
LeaveDate  Start_Time   End_Time
01/01/2017 13:29:00     18:00:00
```

Or

```
LeaveDate  Start_Time   End_Time
01/01/2017 10:00:00     11:00:00
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is change the data types of  your table. The `LeaveDate` should be of type `Date`, ad the `Start_Time` and `End_Time` should be of type `Time`. For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) The next thing to do is to read the [`overlap` tag wiki.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info)

Comment: Also, could something be scheduled to start before midnight and end after midnight? If so, that complicates things.

Comment: This is in SQL Server, there are no Date and Time only datatypes. Only DateTime. Regarding before/after midnight, for now I will not include that feature

Comment: That is not true! Look on all data types ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql)).

Comment: This is SQL Server 2008. [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql) and [`Time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) data types do exist. Unless you are working on an older version, and in that case, please change your version tag.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Apologies, you're correct. I'm pertaining to data types in Visual Studio 2012. There are no Date or Time only datatypes in VS that will handle Date and Time in SQL Server 2008. That's why we use DateTime for dates and string for time.

Comment: Then use SSMS for the database design...

Answer (score 0):

You can check first if the new schedule doesn't overlap with an existing record. Insert if it doesn't, and raise an error if it does.

For example:

```
-- using a table variable for demonstration purposes
declare @Schedule table (Id int identity(1,1) primary key, LeaveDate datetime, Start_Time varchar(8), End_Time varchar(8));

insert into @Schedule (LeaveDate, Start_Time, End_Time) values
('2017-01-01','09:00:00','13:30:00');

declare @LeaveDate date = '2017-01-01';
declare @StartTime time = '13:28:00';
declare @EndTime time = '14:00:00';

if not exists(
    select 1 from @Schedule
    where LeaveDate = convert(datetime,@LeaveDate,20)
      and ((@StartTime > cast(Start_Time as time) and @StartTime < cast(End_Time as time)) or 
           (@EndTime > cast(Start_Time as time) and @EndTime < cast(End_Time as time))
          )
)
begin
    insert into @Schedule (LeaveDate, Start_Time, End_Time) values (@LeaveDate,cast(@StartTime as varchar(8)),cast(@EndTime as varchar(8)));
end
else 
begin
  declare @ErrorMessage varchar(max) = concat('schedule [',convert(varchar,@LeaveDate,20),',',cast(@StartTime as varchar(8)),',',cast(@EndTime as varchar(8)),'] overlaps.');
  RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,16);
end;
```

For the values in the example it would raise the error

```
schedule [2017-01-01,13:28:00,14:00:00] overlaps.
```

Of course, if you would first change the types in the table to date & time then the casts can be avoided.